# test for existance of key with substring

Tags: regex, perl, hash

I have a multidimensional hash/array that looks like this using datadumper;

```
{
          'Customer' => {'123abc' => 
                         {'status' => 
                                     {'New' => 
                                              {'email'=>['user@xxx.com' ], 
                                               'template' => 'XYZ' }
                                                                       }
                                                           },
                        '234' => 
                        {'status' => 
                                    {'New' => 
                                            {'email' => ['user@xxx.com' ],
                                            'template' => 'XYZ' }
                                                                            }
                                                                }

$customers = ("123abc", "234abc", "adb234");
```

I need to test for the existence of a customer based on a complete or partial match from an array value.

The code I am using for complete matches works fine;

```
foreach (@customers) {
if ($config->{Customer}->{$customers[0]}) {
do something
} }
```

This will return a match on "123abc"

But I cannot get it to match when there is the string 234 in $customers[0] or just testing without the array $customers and using just a string.

I have tried;

```
if (/.234*$/ ~~ %config->{Customer})
```

based on an example of Smart Matching on this site "print "We have some teens\n" if /.*teen$/ ~~ %h;".

and

```
if (exists $config->{Customer}->{/234/}
```

as well as using an m at the start of the regex. {m/234/}

Jon

This is written in perl.

Comment: 234 in $customers[0] should match with what? "234abc", "adb234", both??

Comment: What if you replace the smart matching  `/regex/ ~~ "value"` syntax with the customary traditional `"value" =~ /regex/`?

Comment: Also the regex `/.234*$/` looks mildly hosed; you probably mean `/.*234$/` which is more elegantly written as `/234$/`.

Comment: The cirrect way to refer to the hash referenced by `$config->{Customer}` is `%{$config->{Customer}}`. You certainly cannot use a regex as a hash key; it will simply be interpreted as a literal string `$config->{'m/234/'}`. Many of these things would become clear if you would `use strict; use warnings;` as every Perl tutorial tells you.

Comment: I'm not using a regex as a hash key. They key would contain only the substring that I want to match, i.e. "234". The issue is using that value to determine if a key exists in another hash that contains that string , i.e adc234, 234adb. Using a regular regex as you suggested would mean looping through the keys in the config hash for each element in the array that I'm looping through. As for the *234 vs 234*, the example I followed looked for teen at the end, I was looking for the string at the beginning hence the * at the end, assuming * was a wildcard.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to grep across all the keys.

```
my @keys = grep { /234/ } keys %{$config->{Customer}};
if (@keys) {
  # do something, but check for multiple matches...
}
```

Grep returns all elements where the block evaluates to true, with each element being represented by $*.  A regex match (//) defaults to matching against $*.  The above statement could be rewritten as

```
my @keys = grep { $_ =~ /234/ } keys %{$config->{Customer}};
if (@keys) {
  # do something, but check for multiple matches...
}
```

But that's redundant as long as you are familiar with perl.

Comment: I will have to give this some thought when I have the script in front of me when I return on Tuesday.

Comment: The entire flow of the script is to read an xml config file into a hash/array. Then read a file into a hash that has the order number and status. Then perform a SQL query and write the results into a an array. It then loops through the array and tests for status differences with the status hash. if it finds a change, it matches the customer and status in the config hash and if it finds a match, then additional processing is performed. Works great on an exact match, but I need to match multiple customers in the sql results array with a single entry in the config array.